# Haar-$\mathcal{I}$ set and Polish groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a semi-ideal of sets with empty interior on a compact metrizable space $K$. Let an $F_σ$-set $A$ in a Polish group $X$ generically Haar-$\mathcal{I}$.

Then is $A$ always generically Haar-$\mathcal{M}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is the $σ$-ideal of
meager sets in $K$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes" and is given in Proposition 12.16 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06712v2.pdf).